# Problems while creating the object in test method

Tags: java, testing, junit

While I'm trying to create the object for the test method, I get a null pointer exception.

This is the code of the constructor;

```
public Board(int size)
{
    setBoard(size);
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
             board[row][col] = 'E';
         }
    }
}
```

setBoard(int size) code;

```
    public void setBoard(int size)
{
    this.size = size;
}
```

I keep trying but no result yet...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace? And the definition of the method - `setBoard()`. Where is it?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to know "setBoard(int)"?! Try leaving that out first. Just for testing. Your code seems correct to me.

Comment: setBoard method code included on the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `board` is `null`. Change your code to:

```
public Board(int size)
{
    setBoard(size);
    board = new char[size][size]; // initializes the board field
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
             board[row][col] = 'E';
         }
    }
}
```

A nicer version would be:

```
public Board(int size)
{
    setBoard(size);
    board = new char[size][size]; // initializes the board field
    for (char[] row : board) {
        Arrays.fill(row, 'E');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of the `NPE` could be that your `board` `char` array has not been initialized.

```
board = new char[size][size];
```

As you're passing the size in your constructor, you would be unable to determine the correct size of the array when you declare it at class level. Therefore you need to instantiate it in constructor.